# Why nginx gives error 404 not found when i created a new configuration file?

Tags: nginx

I have installed nginx version: nginx/1.17.10 (Ubuntu). The index page which is pointed by "default" configuration file in "sites-enabled" directory works properly. I have created another configuration file in "sites-enabled" called "test.com" and it looks as :

[image]

and

[image]

i have placed the index file in directory...

```
usr/share/nginx/test.com
```

I have edited the hosts configuration in

```
/etc/hosts
```

[image]

now when i do curl test.com i am getting 404 not found error as

[image]

Comment: According your config you have set virtual host `test.com` with a `server_name` directive. Which is saying that it will respond only when you will pass the correct host header in your request. Just add `-H "Host: test.com"` to curl command to pass correct host header.

Comment: sir please explain

Comment: If you do not pass the correct host header then the default config (default site) will take in place and you probably  can get 404 or Nginx default page, it depends of the default config. See details at https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: i am getting curl:no url specified.

Comment: Use this one: `curl -H "Host: test.com" --URL "http://test.com"`

Comment: still i am getting 404 Not Found error.

Comment: my error log shows no such file or directory "/usr/share/nginx/usr/share/nginx/test.com404"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215372/discussion-between-ranjit-vamadevan-and-mgsxman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change:

`root /usr/share/nginx/test.com;`

and

`try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;`